# How to connect to MongoDB in an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mongodb

now I have an iPhone App and basically I want to exchange data from my database (MongoDB) on a server.

Could you please tell me exactly what I should do?

Forgive my innocence, I am a beginner in this area...Thank you very much ahead of time!!

Answer (score 4):

I think you have two options to talk to mongo :

1) Use the rest interface http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface

2) Use Objective-C driver: https://github.com/timburks/NuMongoDB

Comment: ObjCMongoDB (of which I'm author) also has support for iOS: https://github.com/noa--/ObjCMongoDB

Answer (score 2):

If you're not completely tied to MongoDB, have a look at CouchDB. It's essentially the same thing as MongoDB (JSON document store) but for the web. They have a nice built-in REST interface which makes database interaction in mobile/server environments very nice.

http://couchdb.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sid's options, you can also build your own backend that talks to mongodb, that communicates via REST (in your language of choice). This way you can pool your connections on the backend and avoid connectivity issues from the devices.